# ibdata1 increases when firing update queries

Tags: mysql

I have read a lot of posts which explain that the only solution to stop the growth of an ever increasing ibdata1 file is to:

1. Take a dump of all databases
2. Set `innodb_file_per_table` in the `mysqld` section of my.cnf
3. Clean the data directory (except mysql)
4. Restart the MySQL Server and load the dumps using mysqldump.

However my problem starts once I have done all these steps. I still see a scenario where the size of my ibdata1 file increases. The scenario is explained below:

I start MySQL Server 5.5 with a clean data directory (only the mysql directory is present), the size of the ibdata1 file reads 18 MB. Next steps follow:

1. I have the `innodb_file_per_table` entry already mentioned under the mysqld section of my.cnf.
2. Now I load some tables from mysql dump files (all of them have InnoDB storage engine specified) using mysqldump. I observe that ibdata1 size has not changed and separate ibd files have been created which is expected according to the `innodb_file_per_table` setting
3. I add a new column say, `ColumnA (int, NOT NULL, UNSIGNED, DEFAULT 0)` to a table, say Table A. The storage engine is InnoDB and contains 9 million records. So far so good, the size of ibdata1 file remains the same (18 MB)
4. I now update the values in `ColumnA` using the following query: `update TableA set ColumnA = crc32(someothervarcharcolumnfromthistable);`
5. I observe that during the update the size of ibdata1 consistently grows and grows past 300 MB.

Why is this happening? Does this mean I have to do the cleanup-restart-restore activity mentioned at the beginning every 'x' months, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcusAdams the reason of concern is that I am looking for a solution on our live servers and this was just an experiment. On our live server, the ibdata1 file has already increased to 3 GB. Want to get things under control before things run out of control. I am okay with the fact that I have to do the cleanup activity once or 'x' number of times a year. However, need to specifically know why this increase, since space lost in this black hole cannot be reclaimed unfortunately :(

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39125/ibdata1-grows-exponentially-when-innodb-file-per-table-is-configured